# Is it possile to create drill down option in Crystal reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, drilldown

I need to create a drill down report Using crystal report in my asp.net web application. I need to add the drill down option in my details section.  I have done some R&D on this. I could not find any solution for this. If any one have the experience on drill down report Using crystal report Kindly Share with me.

Thanks ..

Comment: -1: this is pretty-basic functionality.  You could have solved this problem by reading the help.

Comment: I need to add the drill down option in my details section. How its possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a group on a field, then `hide` the `details` sections.  You will be able to drill into the `details` section by double clicking the group-header field.

** edit **
The `details` section is the lowest level; no further drill-downs are possible.  You might consider adding a sub-report to the `details` section to provider further, data granularity.

Comment: I need to add the drill down option in my details section. How its possible?

Comment: This is a simple problem,walk through help